# Removing rows from table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume we have table:

```
<table>
    <tr>first</tr>
    <tr class="ClassName">second</tr>
    <tr class="ClassName">third</tr>
</table
```

And We want to remove row with `class='ClassName'`

I wrote a code:

```
var Ids = $('.ClassName').map(function () {
   return this
}).get();
if (Ids.length > 0) {
    for (var i; i = 0; i++) {
         Ids[i].hide();
    }
}
```

*I need to know if there are any rows with this class. If yes I need to remove them. If no I call ajax, read from db and add rows to table. Its part of Show/Hide mechanism*

But my code do nothing. Rows still appear in the page. What should I change?

Comment: I updated question. Unfortunately they can not be hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
// check if are any rows with this class
var $rows = $('table tr.ClassName');
if( $rows.length > 0 ) {
  // remove them or hide with .hide();
  $rows.remove();
} else {
  // call ajax ...
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer so far and in fact the only one meeting the requirements of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
$('table tr.ClassName').hide();
```

Comment: I need to know if there are any rows with this class. If yes I need to  remove them. If no I call ajax, read from db and add rows to table. Its part of Show/Hide mechanism

Comment: Can also be $('table tr.ClassName').remove(); if one wants to remove a row from the DOM

Answer (score 2):

if you want remove permanent then you can use this one.

```
$('.ClassName').each(function(){
      $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: No need to loop through them and remove them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go -

```
$("table tr[class='ClassName']").remove();
```

Please mark this as "Answered" if this solves your problem.

Comment: Why not use the class selector `.ClassName` instead of that more cumbersome attribute selector?

Comment: Since the CSS className can be used on other HTML elements as well, it is recommended to target the type of elements before using class selector. However, if the developer is sure that the mentioned class is only used for the table only then they can directly go for the class selector.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that. I just meant that `$("table tr.ClassName")` is the more straightforward selector, also used by most other answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `hasClass()` in jquery.
**JQuery:**

> //Check if any row has class
>
> if($('table tr').hasClass("ClassName")){    //remove from table    }
>
> else{
>         //do your ajax call here.
>       }

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove all with that class and then check if there was any:

```
$(function () {
    var $trs = $('table tr.ClassName');
    $trs.remove();
    if ($trs.length === 0) {
      // Ajax-call
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
$("table").find(".ClassName").remove();
```

If you want to remove all the table rows other than first row means you can try this

```
$("table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
```